# Rails model associations naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, relationship

I have model User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :selfies
  has_many :likes
  has_many :comments
```

also, have model Selfie:

```
class Selfie < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

also, have model Comment:

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :selfie
```

In my code I can normally use like some instance `@user.comments.count` and I am getting number, but when try to use `@user.selfies.count` I am getting error

> NameError: uninitialized constant User::Selfy

What am I doing wrong here? I was thinking its something about naming conventions but I tried some combinations, selfy selfys selfie ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename your model(and table if need) to Selfy, check this example of what the Rails doing under the hood:

```
$> bundle exec rails console
# convert to table name
"Selfy".tableize 
=> "selfies"
# singular
"selfies".singularize
=> "selfy"
# plural
"selfy".pluralize
=> "selfies"
```

Your AR model must be:

```
class Selfy < ApplicationRecord
end
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :selfy
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :selfies
end
```

Comment: @Nezir it's works for me, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: i tried with renaming a model result the same https://imgur.com/a/utTXX

Comment: @Nezir, you didn't rename the file containing the model though.

Answer (score 3):

Try in rails console:

```
"selfies".singularize # -> "selfy"
```

So that, Rails detect wrong model class. You can do as suggestion of @guitarman but anywhere you use `selfies` you have to do that.

Another way is to create the map between plural and singular of `selfies`. Create `config/initializers/selfies_inflection.rb` and add the map:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'selfie', 'selfies'
end
```